# Playing multiple sounds at contact - Xcode Scene Kit

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit, avaudioplayer, contacts

here's a challenging one I have not found the answer for. This is why I ended up creating an account, stop lurking and being part of the community:

I am coding a game where, when you shake your phone, 5 SCNNodes (boxes with textures of dice) are given an impulse to bounce inside a frame formed by 2 SCNNodes: box & floor. It emulates a poker dice game.

I have coded a contact delegate where I play a sound every time a die hits another die or the box, **but only the first die contacting any of the bodies**, once the impulse starts, **will be the one playing the sound**.

**I am not able to play the same sound simultaneously every time any of the dice contact with each other, the floor or the frame**. I am not able to have that satisfying 'cascade of sounds' when only being able to code with nodeA and nodeB. Many contacts take place at the same time but only one plays the sound.

This is what my code looks like:

```
extension GameViewController : SCNPhysicsContactDelegate {
func physicsWorld(_ world: SCNPhysicsWorld, didBegin contact: SCNPhysicsContact) {

    if (contact.nodeA.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask == BodyType.die.rawValue && contact.nodeB.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask == BodyType.die.rawValue){

        do{
            audioPlayer?.play()
        }catch{
        }
    }else if (contact.nodeB.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask == BodyType.box.rawValue && contact.nodeA.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask == BodyType.die.rawValue){

        do{
            audioPlayer?.play()
        }catch{
        }

}}}
```

The AVaudioPlayer is prepared at the ViewLoad. I have not bothered filling in the **catch** instances.

Here I have an **enum** of categorybitmasks so I can test for contact:

```
enum BodyType:Int {

case die = 1
case box = 2
case floor = 4
```

}

**How can I play the sound anytime any die hits another die, the floor or the frame?**

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it a bit differently, but maybe this will help:

Opinions vary, but I found that SK sound worked better for something like this, so I added an SKOverlay and just used it for sound. Added a couple of sound nodes to spread the usage as I had 100's of objects playing at the same time.  Created a sound class something like:

```
var explosions = [gameTypes: SKAction]()
let vAction = SKAction.playSoundFileName(vName, waitForCompletion: False)
audioNodeAction.run(explosions[soundType]
```

Preload the actions/sounds and then play the sounds below like (enemyMissileHit)

On contacts, I used names of nodes but several ways to do this:

```
guard let nodeNameA = contact.nodeA.name else { return }
guard let nodeNameB = contact.nodeB.name else { return }

if(nodeNameA.prefix(5) == "Explo" && nodeNameB.prefix(5) == "Missi")
{
 gameControl.enemyMissileHit(vIndex: Int(nodeNameB.suffix(4))!)
}
if(nodeNameA.prefix(5) == "Missi" && nodeNameB.prefix(5) == "Explo")
{
 gameControl.enemyMissileHit(vIndex: Int(nodeNameA.suffix(4))!)
}
if(nodeNameA.prefix(5) == "Explo" && nodeNameB.prefix(5) == "Hive ")
{
 gameControl.enemyHiveHit(vIndex: Int(nodeNameB.suffix(4))!)
}
if(nodeNameA.prefix(5) == "Hive " && nodeNameB.prefix(5) == "Explo")
{
 gameControl.enemyHiveHit(vIndex: Int(nodeNameA.suffix(4))!)
}
```

For yours, just name all of your nodes (like Floor) and hopefully that helps.  I had to type this in, so please forgive syntax errors.